# js/html5 printing localStorage 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Storing localStorage on 1 page and trying to print it to a 2nd page when its loaded. Is it possible to print using the method I'm trying? I'm new to js so any help with the syntax using my keys/values would be appreciated.

storing method on 1 page(index.html):

```
 $('form').submit(function() {
var person = $("#FirstName").val() + "." + $('#LastName').val();
 $('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).val(),
       name = $(this).attr('name');
       localStorage[person + "." + name] = value;
       window.location.href = "Confirmation.html";
    console.log('stored key: '+name+' stored value: '+value);
});   
});
```

Trying to print localStorage on 2nd page(Admin.html): except it prints "undefined"

```
document.write(localStorage[name]);
```

Heres the whole page where storing if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/EUWFN/

Comment: ps not to console. needs to print to screen where a user(admin) can view it easily

Comment: Where have you defined `localStorage[name]`?, all I see is `localStorage[person + "." + name]`, being defined.

Comment: just hoping to print a piece of something for starters. I've tried [person + "." + name] but then I get a uncaught reference error (person not defined) etc. Name seems to be the only thing actually printing "undefind" which was a closer than the other

Comment: don't use document.write, use console.log(). Everyone has the power to tell their browser to show the console. You're using this for debugging, so debug, don't use an obsolete and destructive JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage is specific to individual URLs, and cannot be used to "store data across pages". If you have `localStorage["name"] = "jenkins"` on http://example.org/page1, then that localStorage entry exists **only** for http://example.org/page1 and no other page, not even another page on what is otherwise "The same domain" or even "the same subdomain" or even "the same subdomain and subdirectory".

Visiting http://mypage.com/page2 will have its own localStorage object.

What you want is session management, which you enable on the server. Depending on whether you PHP or Node or Django or what have you there are established ways to enable that. Look into them.

Comment: If im still able to view the localStorage within console on the 2nd page, does that mean it is still "shared"?

Comment: you don't see the same localStorage, you see *another* localStorage. On both URLs, clear the localStorage object, and you will see that any changes you make to localStorage on index.html will have absolutely no effect on the content of localStorage on admin.html

Comment: session storage deletes after refreshing iirc. this app will be performed offline and have multiple people take the survey.

Comment: feedback is good so I can continue to understand. However it seems to have the same action. Once I store a survey on 'index' it shows in 'admin' LS console. Once I hit delete LS on 'index', it also deletes on 'admin' after refreshing.